# PHP смена кодировки

Tags: кодировка, php

Здравствуйте! У меня есть дамп mysql базы. Там почти вся инфа кириллицой, но сохранена в windows-1252. Отображается это все дело абракадаброй. Пробую после импорта базы перекодировать пхп-функцией iconv, но видимо такой кодировки она не распознает. Подскажите плз, какое еще решение может быть?

*Обновление*

Файлы как раз в utf-8. Там предыстория данных очень кривая, постараюсь доступно объяснить.

Парсер вытянул данные с ресурса, сразу записал их в БД (Версия сервера: 5.1.69). И уже тогда данные в самом PHPMyAdmin выглядели криво, но на веб странице (Content-Type: utf-8 и пхп-файлы сохранены в utf-8) отображалось абсолютно нормально.

Теперь появилась необходимость смены хостинга, соответственно и поменяли MySQL. Сделал дамп со старого SQL-сервера, импортнул на новый (Версия сервера: 5.1.72-cll-lve - MySQL Community Server (GPL)) и теперь уже ни в PHPMyAdmin ни на сайте инфы не видно - абракадабра.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Для корректной работы, хорошо бы иметь и базу, и страницы сайта в одной кодировке. В связи с этим, мой вопрос мог быть: "В какой кодировке ваши файлы?", но что-то мне подсказывает, что они у вас в какой-угодно кодировке, но только не UTF-8. Поэтому, могу вам посоветовать изменить на эту кодировку документы и в БД выставить сравнение utf8_general_ci. Возможно, что придётся пересоздать дамп, указав для него utf-8 или изменить существующий вручную.

А использовать iconv() - это не выход из данного положения... Точнее - выход, но очень плохой.

*Обновление*

Значит, как я уже писал, вам надо пересоздать дамп. Если вы это делаете через phpMyAdmin, то после перехода на "Экспорт", перейдите в режим "Обычный", и выставить "Кодировка файла" в нужную.

Более геморройный вариант - открыть существующий дамп в текстовом редакторе, изменить его кодировку на utf8, изменить вручную сравнения полей и перезалить в БД, где так же не забыть выставить сравнение utf8_general_ci.

И ещё, можно перестраховаться с помощью указания кодировки, в которой желаете получать данные, SQL-запросом в php:

```
SET NAMES utf8
```

Comment: итак.. дамб уже сделал как надо - везде utf-8 становил, начало отображаться корректно в phpmyadmin, а вот в фронт энде знаки вопроса. проверил - все файлы в кодировке utf-8 (без BOM). это 100%. так же в файле хедера установлены:
header("Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8");
и такое
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
но вот все равно фронт энд лагает. что я еще могу упустить?

Comment: а, забыл упомянуть: статический текст, тот что прям в файлах прописан - отображается корректно, а вот тот что с базы тянется, то слетает кодировка. 
и вот сижу я уже извращаюсь как могу.. пробую изменить кодировку прям в браузере. была установлена кодировка в Юникод. устанавливаю в Кириллица (Windows). результат. статический текст - слутает, из базы - отображается хорошо. значит из базы таки что-то не так вытягивается, но где еще я что-то мог упустить? все таблицы, поля, Сравнение и даже файл дампа был сохранен в utf-8

Comment: @Dzedzik, кодировку после соединения с БД указали? И в htaccess прописать строку:

    AddDefaultCharset UTF-8

Comment: @Deonis, "кодировку после соединения с БД указали?" - это вот не понял.. что это?
а в htaccess строка такая прописана

Comment: @Dzedzik, Самое последнее, что я описал в своем ответе. Не знаю как вы работаете с БД (*MySQLi, PDO или древним способом mysql_* *), поэтому просто показал вам сам запрос. Повторю:

    $query = "SET NAMES utf8";
    // тут выполняете запрос выше

Comment: @Deonis, вот вот вот!! заработало! добавил этот запрос в пхп-файл, сразу после подключения к базе. Вот за это я как раз и не знал.. Спасибо Вам огромное, буду знать теперь.

Answer (score 3):

Посмотрите вот этот вопрос на хэшкоде: http://url-sh.copist.ru/us5

В частности: **в windows-1252 нет кирилицы** ([wikipedia.org/Windows-1252](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows-1252))

А вообще перекодировка базы выполняется так:

1. Делаем резервную копию базы данных
2. Выгружаем дамп. Если разные таблицы в разных кодировках, а такое вполне возможно, то выгружаем таблицы группами по кодировкам.
3. Перекодируем дампы в нужную кодировку.
4. Внутри файла дампов определения кодировки заменяем на нужную
5. Загружаем дампы обратно, выключив проверку ключей, тригеры и перестройку индексов
6. Включаем проверку ключей, тригеры и индексы
7. (!) В приложении, которое общается с базой данных, меняем настройки соединения с базой, чтобы при коннекте устанавливалась правильная кодировка
8. Проверяем работу приложения: формы поиска, вставки и редактирования записей по всем сущностям

В идеальном случае всё проходит с одним дампом за четыре команды: выгрузить, перекодировать, заменить определения кодировки, загрузить обратно.

Могут быть сложности. Например, поля типа TEXT (BLOB, CLOB) могут быть выгружены потоком байтов в кодировке BASE64 и на них перекодировка не подействует. Их надо будет программно перекодировать строка за строкой.

Или у таблицы была указана одна кодировка (UTF8), а вставляли в другой (windows - 1251).

Или программист очухался и поменял настройку кодировки при соединении с базой, но забыл переконвертировать, и теперь в таблицах данные частично в одной кодировке, частично в другой. Вот в таких случаях iconv выдаёт ошибку "Illegal char". Вселенская печаль.